# How do I change the cell tile in a tilemap java libgdx

Tags: java, android, set, tiles, tile

Im creating a simple fall down game, and want to be able to randomly generate the next line. I am using the libgdx TiledMapTiles to get the properties of these tiles. What I am struggling with is actually setting the tile to a tile in my tileset with a specific property. My code is below:

```
    public TiledMapTile cellChanger() {

    Iterator <TiledMapTile> tiles = map.getTileSets().getTileSet("tiles").iterator();
    TiledMapTile newTile = null;

    while(tiles.hasNext()) {
        TiledMapTile tile = tiles.next();

            if(tile.getProperties().containsKey("white")) {
                newTile = tile;
            }

    }
    return newTile;

}
```